# Underlines under text that do not flow to the other page

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using the KOMA script `srcbook` class, and my plan is to have text and horizontal lines under each section of text for writing.

For example

```
\chapter{1}

this is a sentence
\oneline
etc.
```

Where `\oneline` is defined as

```
\newcommand{\oneline}{
\vspace{0.6cm}
\hrule
\vspace{0.3cm}
}
```

There are a lot of problems with this approach. I cannot use footnotes (because the horizontal lines get cut off), and the horizontal lines flow onto the next page.

Is there a simple way to create a horizontal line under text such that it does not flow onto the next page, or at least so that the text and the horizontal lines are grouped together?

I am aware that floats can be used to include graphics, is it a good approach here?

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a full yet minimal compilable code showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `\nobreak`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcommand*{\oneline}{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{6mm}%
    \hrule
    \nobreak\vspace{3mm}%
}



\begin{document}

Let's skip to the bottom of the page:

\vspace{543pt} % then try incrementing this to 544pt

Some text.
\oneline
Some other text.

\end{document}
```

**Addition:** It is perhaps a good idea to make the `\oneline` macro “stable” w.r.t. interline glue too.  You might want to reduce the amount of vertical spacing (6mm, 3mm) to smaller values, in this case.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcommand*{\oneline}{%
    \vskip -\prevdepth
    \par\nobreak\vskip 6mm
    \hrule
    \nobreak\vskip 3mm \relax
    \setlength\prevdepth{0pt}%
}



\begin{document}

Let's skip to the bottom of the page:

\vspace{537pt} % then try incrementing this to 538pt

Some text, with descenders: fgjpqy.
\oneline
Some other text.

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
\showlists

\end{document}
```